# building custom type in powershell from a derived class

Tags: c#, powershell-2.0

I am trying to build a specific list with my own base object  and some special features in my list.
It works very well as an exe. But do not work when i try to import the equivalent dll in powershell.

```
    add-type @"
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace myTest
{
    public class stuff
   {
       public int val;
       public stuff(int val)
      {
       this.val = val;
      }
   }
   public class tata : List<stuff>
   {
     int val ;
     ..
   }
}
"@
```

while calling the class with :

```
$example = new-object myTest.stuff ->Works
$example2 = new-object myTest.tata ->Does not work
```

I cannot intanciate myTest.tata but the type seems to be declared.
seems that the problem comes from

```
 public class tata: List<stuff>
```

something in powershell cannot interpret this line

Did someone had the same problem and solved the issue ?

Answer (score 2):

The code you sent worked fine for me, apart from warning that val is never used. So I had to IgnoreWarnings

```
    add-type "
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace myTest
{
    public class stuff
    {
        public int val;
        public stuff(int val)
        {
            this.val = val;
        }
    }
    public class tata : List<stuff>
    {
        int val;
    }
} " -IgnoreWarnings

$example = new-object myTest.stuff(1)
$example2 = new-object myTest.tata
$example2.GetType().Name
```

It gave me tata as output
Can you check if what you sent is actually what gives you problem?